Tension map and Wrinkles
I am having some problems with geometry node specifically regarding tension map and wrinkles for the past week. I have a rig that I thought would look better with some wrinkles, so I searched online to see what solutions people have come up with.  I found a few of them, and I followed the tutorials to understand the logic behind it. Most of the tutorials requires making a duplicate for reference, and they also started from curves which is different than my situation, I already have a mesh built and rigged.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNGGwaHOzHY&t=684s I followed this one first because it's more recent and more simplified, I think I redo this one a few times just because I want to change some stuff to fit my situation (Not starting from curve, have existing mesh, don't want to duplicate mesh)  After I failed the first time, I gave in to duplicating mesh, but still not successful, when I move the rigs away from the duplicated mesh, the tension map behaves weirdly.  Someone here gave me this link last week.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz2yZdivwnU&t=12s  I downloaded the blender file and recreated the nodes, but it looked more complicated than the first one, it also started with curves, and the tension map was set up so it triggers compression and stretch normal maps which I don't like cus I already have texture, I am more looking for geometry change.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjmAXqpP5tc&t=832s  I am currently looking into this one, seems to be what I want, but it has it's own issues (mainly the duplicate mesh, and also blender changed transfer attribute node, instead I have to use sample index node, and Im not getting the same result)  Sorry for the long message, but I think this is way over my head.  I tried to Mcguyver it, but Im not having any luck.  So I guess my question is, is it possible to have tension map/wrinkle without duplicating the mesh, and also if there's anyone who has successfully created a tension map wrinkles recently on their rig??  I came across this video about Implementing shape keys in Geometry node, it looks interesting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0awxRsDK2uc&t=6s  I want to bring it up before I go into another rabbit hole and waste more time, thanx.


this is my modifiers stack


OMG, I think I got the color to show up, I think I am getting closer to the fold

You can try my setup if you want, I've described it here (ru language, you can try google translate if you want)
The core element is using rest position attribute, This is the node setup that I've used:

GN defines the distance between the points: the current one and the original one recorded in the Rest Position attribute. This is how the difference in edge lengths gets.
Then this difference is written to the mesh vertices using the Evaluate on domain node. If you need to keep direction, you can save it on edge domain.
The result is saved to a new attribute, I called it "FaceArea" in the screenshot.
Please note! GN modifier should be located after armature and before any subdivisions, because subdivision changes the size of edges.
The result (folds on the coat):


Thank you so much, I will do through the material and try to digest, will be back to update the progress soon

Hey Mikhail, it's so funny to read through your post, I am going through the same struggle you went through a while ago, I spent a lot of time playing with clothes simulation and all the stuff you mention and I also came to the conclusion about using the tension map to create folds and stuff.  I saw that you have 2 separate geometry nodes graphs?  or is one a group node?

Hi Crantisz, I read your post many times yesterday and today, I tried to follow your instructions, but I have some questions.  Are (node tree for calculating compression/extension) and (for adding folds to a subdivided surface) under the same geometry node tree?  Where do you put the color ramp node in the compression/extension map if you want to see the red/blue colors?  In your setup for adding folds, there are many group inputs.  I am pretty new to Blender, i thought you can only have one group input and one group output each tree??

The second node tree in the original post is used after subdivision modifier to add displacement on high detailed surface. They are separated, because you can't use the rest position attribute on a subdivided model. Blue/red map you can get if you read custom FaceArea attribute and map it from -1...1 to 0....1 (map range node). You can add any number of group inputs, to make the node tree more readable.

Hi Crantisz, I have referenced your set up for the tension map, and also implemented your suggestion for the red/blue map.  The color is not showing up, I am wondering if you could take a look at my node to see if I am missing anything?   I have attribute (FaceSice) connect to the Material Output.

Hi, could you also explain how did you create the fold attribute?? Thanks

What do you mean? It doesn't require any special creation process.

Hey Crantisz, I have posted a longer response in the post above, thank you for your help.

Is it possible for you to share a screen grab of your tension map geometry node setup with the blue/red map integrated? I added a multiply node before the store named attribute node to exaggerate the effect, I think it works, but I just can't get it to show the red/blue color.

For the fold map, could you go into details on how you created it? Did you use height map as a base? I had to create the fold procedurally and I am curious how you create the fold. In your fold map's Group input, you have created a lot of output (Geommetry, Image in, Image out, folds in mult, folds out mult, and offset) What are their type and subtype? I think your method could work, but I need more info, thank you so much for your help.

I just painted it by hand. And all these "in mult" (multiply) just controls how much displace you want to see.

Hey Crantisz, Thank you so much, it works, I am in the process of  weight painting the fold vertex group, testing out the subdivison surface and multires modifiers to see which way is better and stuff, will update my post once I have more to show, thanx again

Mark answer as correct then
